# TTabSet - Wrong tab positions in Delphi XE8

Tags: delphi, tabs, delphi-xe8

In a Delphi project I use the somewhat antique (but nevertheless still useful) TTabSet VCL component with a total of 26 tabs (labeled 'A' to 'Z'). Everything worked fine when compiled with Delphi 7. With Delphi XE8, however, the TTabSet method ItemAtPos returns slightly wrong values. This published method which is also used internally for determining the index of the clicked tab may finally cause the wrong tab to be selected. This bug becomes paticularly prominent when clicking a tab having a rather high tab index. In my project clicking the 'X' or 'Y' tab e.g. will cause the 'Z' tab to be selected. This behavior has been observed with both the Classic Look as well with the Aero Look of Windows 7.

As a preliminary workaround I have sucessfully patched and recompiled the unit Vcl.Tabs.pas in the following way: In the function TTabSet.ItemAtPos(...) I have slightly modified the formulas for calculating the local variables MinLeft and MaxRight as shown in the following code snippet (lines 958 to 975):

```
    for I := 0 to FTabPositions.Count - 1 do
    begin
      TabPos := TTabPos(FTabPositions[I]);
//***************** original Delphi XE8 ********************
{
      MinLeft := TabPos.StartPos - Extra;
      MaxRight := TabPos.StartPos + TabPos.Size + Extra;
}
//******************* Michael's patch **********************
      MinLeft  := TabPos.StartPos               - Extra + I;
      MaxRight := TabPos.StartPos + TabPos.Size + Extra + I;
//**********************************************************
      if (Pos.X >= MinLeft) and (Pos.X <= MaxRight) then
      begin
        Result := FirstIndex + I;
        Break;
      end;
    end;
```

With this patch, now everything works fine also with Delphi XE8.

Question: Is this a viable way to deal with this obvious bug or does anybody else have a better idea to solve this problem?

Comment: The issue has been reported to Embarcadero Quality Central on 26th of May, 2014 with number 125088 and is a duplicate of 91874. [Link](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=125088) 

A workaround is reported to be not to use tab styles tsStandard or tsSoft.

Comment: The QC report mentioned previously talks about an error of 1 pixel per tab, as I understand your fix also assumes. The error might as well be in the calculation of tab positions (for the `FTabPositions` list) in `TTabSet.CalcTabPositions`.

Comment: Reading the Embarcadero Quality Central Report #91874 (thanx for this link) has reassured me, that my workaround (which I had found out independently) should be a good way to cope with this bug. However, all of my attempts to fiddle around with the `FTabPositions` list in `TTabSet.CalcTabPositions` had unwanted side effects and were therefore abandoned.